# How to create nodes and collections(table equivalent in mysql)

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra,
I have more than 10 years experience of working with mysql and sql server and it makes my job harder to transfer to nosql databases.

As you know sql databases provide very user friendly workbrench for working with them.

But the only thing that I found for cassandra was datastax and I am not even sure if I can even create nodes and colloections in a visualize way and not by command line. Is it possible to do such a thing in cassandra ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpsCenter and DevCenter, both from DataStax. OpsCenter lets you do operations-centric tasks, while DevCenter lets you perform developer-centric tasks.